# Passing a selenium docker container IP to a ruby cucumber script

Tags: ruby, docker, cucumber, watir

I'm attempting to put a ruby Cucumber test into Docker. I'm using a docker-compose.yml file to start a selenium hub container along with a chrome and firefox node. Then I'm building an alpine ruby based image with my tests.

I've gotten the process to work, however it involves finding the IP of the hub container each time it is built, and then hardcoding the IP into my env.rb file where I connect to the Selenium grid.

I've seen that containers that are linked can be connected using the name but haven't had much luck there. Is there any way I can easily pass the hub container IP to my test's container?

Here is my yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:

  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"

    environment:
      GRID_MAX_SESSION: 16
      GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT: 3000
      GRID_TIMEOUT: 3000

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    container_name: web-automation_chrome
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 4
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 4
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "9001:5900"
    links:
      - hub

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    container_name: web-automation_firefox
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 2
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 2
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "9002:5900"
    links:
      - hub

  myapp:
    build: .
    image: justinpshields/myapp
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      URL: hub
    links:
      - hub

networks:
  default:
```

Comment: Have you read [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation?  Communicating between containers you should be able to use the Compose service names `hub`, `chrome`, `firefox`, `myapp` as host names; you do not need `links:` and should probably delete them.

Comment: I hadn't seen that page so thank you. And I'll remove the links. The part I'm struggling with still is how to pass the actual IP of the hub. I've tried setting an env variable but that doesn't seem to be picked up within the tests.

Comment: You can't use `hub` as a DNS name?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a ton of experience in this, do you just mean setting remote URL of my tests to "http://hub:4444/wd/hub"?

Answer (score 0):

`links` is useless. Every container in a `docker-compose.yml` share the same network unless stated otherwise.

You should also wait until the selenium hub start and attach its browsers containers.

For instance with that:

```
while ! curl -sSL "http://$SELENIUMHUBHOST:4444/status" 2>&1 | grep "\"ready\": true" >/dev/null; do
  echo 'Waiting for the Grid'
  sleep 1
done
while ! curl -sSL "http://$SELENIUMHUBHOST:4444/status" 2>&1 | grep "\"browserName\": \"$BROWSER\"" >/dev/null; do
  echo "Waiting for the node $BROWSER"
  sleep 1
done
```